# Java: Use parallel stream to copy files

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, file-copying

I am studying computer science at a University, and I have been assigned to create a **'normal'** program, a program using implicit concurrency **(parallel streams)** and a program using explicit concurrency **(threadpool)**

I have created a batch file copier (source to destination) using the **Java.NIO** lib.
I am trying to figure out how it would be possible to be done using **parallel streams.**

I have a **String array** which contains the file paths/names, and then I have this loop in order to copy the files to the destination:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < filelist.length){
    String filepath = filelist[i];
    Path source = Paths.get(filepath);
    Path target = Paths.get(FileBrowser.destinationpath+"/"+filenames[i]);  

    try {
        //replace existing file using java nio package
        System.out.println(Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    i++;
}
```

Any help on how to do this by using **parallel streams** would be appreciated.

PS. I **know** that copying files in parallel would not result in the files being copied faster rather than sequential, since **it is not a CPU matter and more of a disk matter**. Either way this assignment is to test and report results so that's why I have chosen this approach.

Comment: it could be faster if you have more than one disk. Also note that you would probably get better results with a parallel stream on Java 9 vs 8 because the performance has been improved: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072773

Comment: @assylias thank you for the heads up, is what I am asking possible though? I can't seem to figure out how to apply that chunk of code as parallel stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 8, you can iterate over any list as a parallel stream. So using your code, you could do something as the following:

```
Arrays.asList(filelist).parallelStream().forEach((filepath) -> {
    Path source = Paths.get(filepath);
    Path target = Paths.get(FileBrowser.destinationpath+"/"+filepath]);
    try {
        //replace existing file using java nio package
        System.out.println(Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I can't use this:
    Path target = Paths.get(FileBrowser.destinationpath+"/"+filepath);

I have a different string array for the filename,

Path target = Paths.get(FileBrowser.destinationpath+"/"+filenames[i]);

Comment: I have modified your answer and it works :) I get better times copying files through this parallel stream too!

Files: 85
Total Size: 440.57 MB

NORMAL
38.79
35.98
36.24

PARALLEL
32.93
32.63
35.19

THREADPOOL
37.53
40.06
36.01